# Xcode 4.6.1 crashes after installing OSX Yosemite

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

i was working with xcode 4.6.1 with OSX Maverick, today i installed OSX Yosimite 10.10 then suddenly xcode keep crashing, i can't even open the XCode.

I have pasted the trace log here. any help how to solve this will be grateful. Thanks.

### Log

> Application Specific Information:
>   ProductBuildVersion: 4H512
>   UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Error getting value for key 'delegateClass' of extension 'Xcode.IDEiPhoneOrganizer.MenuDefinition.Screenshots' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport'
>   UserInfo: {
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 \"Loading a plug-in failed.\" UserInfo=0x4031d3980 {DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEiPhoneSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEiPhoneSupport, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEiPhoneSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in \U201ccom.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport\U201d at path \U201c/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEiPhoneSupport.ideplugin\U201d could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x401bb9100 \"The bundle \U201cIDEiPhoneSupport\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.\"}";
>   }

Comment: reinstall Xcode and see if that fixes it

Comment: It won't.  You'll almost certainly need to start hosing `~/Library/Developer/Xcode` and other directories.

Comment: I have reinstalled the xcode 4.6.1 but it dosen't work it keep prompting me the same error. Mr.Droppy its not that clear to me how to do the hosting as you mentioned, if you could elaborate on this would be a great help.

Comment: Got any solutions (that doesn't need partitioning)?

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to Yosemite and needed Xcode 4.4.1 to maintain a personal project that runs on a 2nd generation iPod touch.

The best solution I found was to partition my Yosemite drive and install Mavericks and the old version of Xcode on the new partition. Note that you’ll have to install Mavericks from an external drive or a USB stick. I followed [these instructions](http://www.macworld.com/article/2056561/how-to-make-a-bootable-mavericks-install-drive.html).

Answer (score 0):

stating the obvious maybe, but have you considered upgrading your xcode? or did this error occur during an upgrade attempt? I'm sure 4.6 was not designed for Yosemite (as xcode 6.x is already out and work well for me under Yosemite)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: yes xcode 6 works fine but the problem is , if i use xcode 6 there are number of issues occurred in my project. So i have to spend may be two three weeks to get this done. I know this is not good i have already start migrating to xcode 6 but i need xcode 4.6.1 to do the client releases until then.

Comment: If you're working with Cross Platform applications, viewing, let alone editing, NIB files with XCode 5 or 6 that were created with Xcode 4, will cause problems when compiling with gnuStep.